# Proof verification: Every Euclidean space is complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

To prove this, I would like to use induction.
For $n=1$ it is easy to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

For $n=k$ we assume it is true.

For $n=k+1$, we have to show that $\mathbb {R}^{k+1}$ is complete.
Let $(x_n,y_m) $ be a cauchy seq. in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ and converging to $(x_0,y_0) $ we show that $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb {R}^{k+1}$
Now, $\{x_n\}$ is conv. to $x_0$ and $\{x_n\}\subset\mathbb {R}^k $  and $\mathbb{R}^k $ is complete by part 2,so $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^k $
And $\{y_m\}$ converging to $y_0$ and $\{y_m\}\subset\mathbb {R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete by part 1, so $y_0\in\mathbb{R} $
Hence $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb {R}^{k+1} $

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If you take a Cauchy sequence and want to prove completeness, you cannot assume that it converges to some point. This is exactly what you need to prove.

Comment: Why was the title edited? The content of the question doesn't make any sense now.

Comment: "it is easy to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete." I'm curious about your easy proof.

Answer (score 3):

No induction needed. Every projection map is distance decreasing so if $(\vec{v})_n$ is Cauchy so are all sequences $(\vec{v}_i)_n$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$, if we're working in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

By completeness of the reals, each of these has a limit $p_i$. And a sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}^N$ iff it converges in every coordinate, so $(\vec{v})_n \rightarrow (p_1,\ldots,p_N)$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your proof is incorrect. As Cornelis said in the comment, your assumption "converging to $(x_0,y_0)$" is logically wrong.

[Added:] Also, your notation $(x_n,y_m)$ doesn't make sense.

Let $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^k $. You need to *show* that it has a limit.

You need to show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Thus by the induction hypothesis, they both have limit, $x_0$ and $y_0$ respectively. Now you show that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$.

---

[Added:] Here is the induction step for the proof.

Suppose $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^k$. It follows (this step depends on how you understand Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for any positive integer $d$) that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Using the induction hypothesis, $x_n\to x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $y_n\to y_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ for *some* $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^k$. Now what you need to show is $(x_n,y_n)\to(x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$.

Comment: We assume (xn,ym) is cauchy i.e. each of xn and ym is cauchy ..and by induction hypothesis xn is conv. to x0 in R^k is conv. to y0 in R

Comment: Your "i.e." part needs a verification.

Comment: How can i verify this?

Comment: Can you prove this by induction, and send it to me?

Comment: Try first to write down by definition what  "$\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ is Cauchy" means.

Comment: Means each of them are cauchy. 

Comment: Well, if you take that as a *definition* of Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  it is OK.